# Drive shaft Is loose?

Tags: transmission, rear-differential, drive-shaft

My rear drive shaft (?) disattached on the road, making a really nasty sound. I managed to put it back in place. It is really loose, you can pull it out with hands. See before and after pics below. How can I make it stay in place? Im at the repair shop now but they are busy for another 4 days.Thank you. I bought the car a month ago.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is hard to tell from the photo, but I presume the bearing had failed.  If so, you wont be able to make a temporary fix.

Comment: What is the year/make/model/engine/transmission of the car in question? If we are looking at the rear differential, I'd suggest you are going to end up replacing the differential, but really without further information about the car, that's a guess.